# Make dropdown list for field city in magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

I want to custom field "City" to dropdown list in checkout page (magento 2.1.5).

Is it possible? How can do that?

[image]

New update:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to figure it out?

Comment: you are checking on checkout page. But you written code for cart page. So check your cart page. You can see dropdown there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is no option in magento2 for making the city field as dropdown like state and country in the checkout page.

An approach would be to add relations to the directory_country and/or directory_country_region tables to only show cities which belong to the specific country or region selected in the checkout.

you will need to overwrite of the class \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor by using 'options' value provided by the third party api for city(or use a custom array):-

```
 $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  '',
            'options' => array_option(),
        ],
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your way, but seem to not work. Does I need to changes anything else?
I have changed in: vendor\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.

Please review my new attach image above.

Thanks!

Comment: @TriAnhHuynh If you have fixed this please share you code

Comment: please share  your code i also have the same requirement